# Creating ActiveX ComboBoxes Locks Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that is intended to create a series of combo boxes on a worksheet. Since I cannot be in break mode when creating combo boxes I am struggling to find out what I am doing wrong.

```
Private Sub CreatePlayerSelectorComboBoxes()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Dim currStatusBarMgr As StatusBarManager
    Set currStatusBarMgr = New StatusBarManager
    currStatusBarMgr.MessagePrefix = "Creating Control: "
    With MatchesTeamPlayersWS
        .Range(.Cells(17, 1), .Cells(17, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)).ClearContents
        Dim matchCounter As Long
        For matchCounter = 1 To 6
            Dim controlColumnMatch As Long
            controlColumnMatch = ((matchCounter - 1) * 24)
            Dim matchText As String
            matchText = "M" & matchCounter
            Dim teamCounter As Long
            For teamCounter = 1 To 2
                Dim controlColumnTeam As Long
                controlColumnTeam = ((teamCounter - 1) * 12)
                Dim teamText As String
                Select Case teamCounter
                    Case Is = 1
                        teamText = "TmA"
                    Case Is = 2
                        teamText = "TmB"
                End Select
                Dim positionCounter As Long
                For positionCounter = 1 To 4
                    Dim positionText As String
                    positionText = "P" & positionCounter
                    Dim controlText As String
                    controlText = matchText & teamText & positionText
                    Dim currDivAControlName As String
                    currDivAControlName = "DivA" & controlText
                    Dim currDivBControlName As String
                    currDivBControlName = "DivB" & controlText
                    Dim controlColumnPosition As Long
                    controlColumnPosition = 3 + ((positionCounter - 1) * 3)
                    Dim controlColumn As Long
                    controlColumn = controlColumnMatch + controlColumnTeam + controlColumnPosition
                    Dim controlCell As Range
                    Set controlCell = .Cells(17, controlColumn)
                    currStatusBarMgr.PostStatusBarUpdate (currDivAControlName)
                    Debug.Print currDivAControlName
                    Dim controlDivA As Variant
                    Set controlDivA = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                                        Link:=False, _
                                        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                                        Left:=controlCell.Left, _
                                        Top:=controlCell.Top, _
                                        Width:=140, _
                                        Height:=24)
                    controlDivA.Name = currDivAControlName
                    currStatusBarMgr.PostStatusBarUpdate (currDivBControlName)
                    Debug.Print currDivBControlName
                    Dim controlDivB As Variant
                    Set controlDivB = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
                                        Link:=False, _
                                        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
                                        Left:=controlCell.Offset(0, 144).Left, _
                                        Top:=controlCell.Offset(0, 144).Top, _
                                        Width:=140, _
                                        Height:=24)
                    controlDivB.Name = currDivBControlName
                Next
            Next
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

If I comment out the parts that are intended to create the combo boxes the code runs. I have inspected the Set assignments and they appear to be syntactically correct. I have also made sure the names are unique.

I have let Excel run and run.. All I get is [running]... until I force-quit Excel.

Comment: You've got some `Debug.Print`'s and Status Bar messages in there: what clues do those give you?

Comment: Just tried your code, and for me it runs to completion is a few seconds.  Possible reasons yours fails include: you might be triggering an Event Cascade. Your issue might be inside `StatusBarManager` (which I commented out).

Comment: @chrisneilsen - thanks for looking and at least confirming that it does work. I am beginning to wonder if the workbook itself is somehow corrupted. The `Debug.Print` and `StatusbarManager` were added to try to determine where things fail. Since you don't have my StatusBarManager class you  would indeed need to comment it out. The clues the `Debug.Print` and `StatusBarManager` are the same: `Debug.Print` puts the very first `currDivAControlName` in the immediate window; the `StatusBarManager` puts that same text in the Status Bar... and then nothing more.

Comment: FWIW, I created a new workbook, copied the cells from the troubled one into the new, imported the module with the above code, renamed the sheet and renamed the code name. The sheet in the new WB replicates the problem WS. The code runs fine. All I can figure is that the file I was working with is corrupt or at a minimum the WS is corrupt.

Comment: I found the culprit (I think). I had a UDF and it is `Volatile`. I removed all calls in all cells to that UDF and the code works as it should. Lesson learned.